# HTTP call to IP instead of domain

Tags: ios, http, ip, app-store

I have my iOS APP which needs to make an HTTP call. The problem is that I dont have a domain, so I make the call to the public IP address of the server (e.g `194.66.82.11`).

So, is there any chance that my app get rejected from the **Apple** AppStore because it make HTTP call to an IP address instead of domain ?

Comment: i can't see why they would reject based on that.  all host names get resolved to IP addresses anyway.

Comment: @michael i hope at some point you realize he is asking if APPLE will reject his app

Comment: @michael the OP clearly asked if apple will reject his app from the app store.  what's that got to do with HTTP calls to an apple web server?  anyway OP, submit your app :)

Comment: @michael.  again explaining host headers etc. has nothing to do with whether or not apple WILL or WON'T reject the app (which was the OPs question).  you're grasping now :)  anyway its a pointless discussion.  move on.